# Remove padding below tableHeaderView in iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've added a label to my `tableHeaderView` in the interface builder. However, I want to reduce the padding between the header and first table view. (e.g. between "Round 1" and "Match 1"). Is that possible?

[image: header]

Comment: You can set `tableHeaderView.frame` whatever you want.

Comment: I tried reducing the size of `tableHeaderView.frame` but that didn't help.

Comment: Ok, run `Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy` and examine frames. What creates this gap?

Comment: BTW, how **exactly** did you reduce size of `tableHeaderView`?

Comment: Please see the accepted answer below. Turns out the padding was caused by the section height, not the `tableHeaderView` height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this method

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section==0)
    return 50.0f;
else
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: This helped, thank you! However, the code didn't work as you wrote it. I had to use `if (section == 0) { 30.0f } else { 50.0f } `.